# Selenium IDE y WebDriver

Tags: java, web, selenium, test, junit

He empezado un proyecto de test unitarios de una web. 
Para esto me he decidido a usar Selenium, pero he tenido una serie de dudas y problemas.

En la web se encuentra Selenium IDE y el WebDriver, este segundo parece que está un poco abandonado, y da problemas con las versiones más modernas de los navegadores, mientras que el IDE deja la programación a un lado, y parece que en las ultimas versiones del IDE no hay forma de sacar el código que genera.

Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce una herramienta mejor, o sabe como sacar el código en JAVA de los archivos que genera Selenium IDE.

Comment: Bienvenido @Jorege, mi recomendacion es que generes tu el codigo Java. Para pruebas sencillas no tendras ningun problema. Existen muchos ejemplos que te pueden facilitar tu comienzo con las pruebas con Selenium. Por otro lado para hacer test unitarios yo te recomiendo usar JUnit es una de sus cualidades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me paso algo similar, pero logre generar el código utilizando `Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for Chrome)`. Una vez teniendo el código baje el `geckoDriver` y lo pegue en una carpeta en C:

Luego en la clase que genera `Katalon Recorder` hice esto:

```
@Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckoDriver/geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true); 
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    //driver = new ChromeDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
    Dimension initial_size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    height = initial_size.getHeight();
    width = initial_size.getWidth();
    System.out.println(height+ ","+width);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    initial_size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    height = initial_size.getHeight();
    width = initial_size.getWidth();
    System.out.println(height+ ","+width);

    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height-175));

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

El resto es agregar los jars necesarios, y usar el resto del código generado por `Katalon Recorder` en el metodo

```
@Test
  public void testMonitoreo() throws Exception {
```