# Obtener nombres de controles aplicación externa

Tags: c#, vb.net, java-ee, aplicación-web, webforms

Quisiera saber si es posible obtener los nombres de los controles de una aplicación externa (Oracle Web Forms) dado que actualmente hago mucho trabajo repetitivo con esta aplicación. Por ello me vi en la necesidad de programarme una aplicación de escritorio en VB.Net que, mediante coordenadas, envia pulsaciones de teclas o parametros a ciertos controles de esa aplicación externa.

El problema que tengo con las coordenadas es que al no ser de mi autoria dicha aplicación externa el programador puede agregar o mover los controles "X" pixeles y con eso mi aplicación deja de funcionar, lo mismo pasa al tener otra resolución de pantalla o redimensionar la misma, mi aplicación no encuentra el o los controles indicados en la posición que tengo.

Por ello quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de obtener los nombres de los controles, cabe mencionar que el web form no hay forma de inspeccionarlo como una pagina web normal con F12 o Inspeccionar.

Es posible? Como? O alguna sugerencia para que la app con coordenadas sea funcional?

Al parecer no hay opción de obtener el nombre de los controles he estado googleando bastante y no encuentro como obtener los nombres de los controles.

Se me ocurre abrir la ventana de la aplicación externa a cierta dimensión y así enviar los parametros a la coordenada indicada, aunque el problema aun existiria si agregan algún control.

Como podria realizar la apertura de la aplicación externa a la dimensión que yo requiera?

Comment: La aplicacion que se pretende controlar se puede manejar unicamente usando teclado?

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella
Si, Teclado para meter datos y mouse para dar clic a los botones.

Comment: podrias usar la clase sendkeys https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.8 y para los botones verificar si con alguna combinacion de teclas puedes emular el raton

Comment: @LuisCarlosDonadoAvella
De hecho con eso no tengo problemas, es lo que uso en mi aplicación el problema es que si me mueven o agregan controles la app no funiona como debiera.

            'Add List Name
            Thread.Sleep(1500)
            SetCursorPos(50, 106)
            mouse_event(LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            mouse_event(LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            Clipboard.Clear()
            Clipboard.SetText(CWO.Trim)
            Thread.Sleep(1500)
            SendKeys.Send("^v")

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas usar es [Selenium](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium).[Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) automatiza los navegadores. Es un entorno de pruebas de software para aplicaciones basadas en la web.

Consiste en 3 partes:

El [webdriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) es un archivo executable (driver) que te permite controlar el navegador en cuestión. [El driver depende del navegador que quieras controlar](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

La 2da parte es [selenium-ide](/questions/tagged/selenium-ide) que es lo que te permite grabar y reproducir pruebas como si de una macro se tratara. Es una especie de plugin para los navegadores. Yo tuve algunos problemas para que me generara el código hasta que encontré [Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).Puede generar código para el lenguaje que escojas.

La 3ra parte es una [API de selenium](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208235/3834) que te permite levantar el navegador que escojas por medio del web driver y ejecutar el código de la macro grabado con selenium ide. Esta API existe para cualquier lenguaje.

Te recomiendo buscar videotutoriales para que observes su uso.

Comment: Voy a investigar algo de Selenium, he usado WebScraping con Python y WebDriver alguna ocasion para descargar informacion de paginas web, aunque me quede atorado ya que las paginas usan Json para volcar los datos y mostrarlos en la pagina y es dificil extraer la informacion que requieres al no tener los nombres de las columnas necesarias.